# boost::asio async handlers invoked without error after cancellation

Tags: c++, windows, handler, boost-asio, asyncsocket

My code uses boost::asio and io_service in a single thread to perform various socket operations. All operations are asynchronous and every handler depends on the `boost::system::error_code` (particularly `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`) to determine the result of the operation.

It's been working perfectly well until I changed the logic to make several **concurrent** connections and pick the fastest one. That is, when the first `async_read_some` handler fires, I cancel other sockets (shutdown, close - everything) and proceed with the current one. In 95% of cases other sockets' read handlers are invoked with the operation_aborted error. However sometimes, these read handlers are invoked without errors, telling me that they have successfully received N bytes.

But the documentation for socket::cancel() [states](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel/overload2.html):

> This function causes all outstanding asynchronous connect, send and
>   receive operations to finish immediately, and the handlers for
>   cancelled operations will be passed the `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` error.

So, the questions: Can I really rely on the `operation_aborted` error in production code? If I can, is it a bug in Asio from boost 1.46.1? If I can't, is there any official documentation regarding this?

Comment: It seems in your case that multiple handlers have "succeeded" before the cancel was invoked.  You can rely on the `operation_aborted` to be passed to any handlers that have not already executed (and are waiting to be called).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, the answers:

1. No, I cannot rely on the `operation_aborted` error only.
2. Of course, it's not a bug in Asio, just a lack of experience on my side.
3. There is a little bit of official [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/cancel/overload1.html). It's for timers, not sockets, however the same principles apply:

---

If the timer has already expired when cancel() is called, then the handlers for asynchronous wait operations will:

- have already been invoked; or
- have been queued for invocation in the near future.

---

Basically, I was wrong in assumption that if I use a single thread for io_service, then every operation will be blocked while some handler executes.

The behavior I'm reporting actually makes a lot of sense and it seems that everyone who uses Asio knows that. I've combed through Asio's mailing lists and have found a lot of discussion on the subject [here](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=23289194), [here](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=23509457), [here](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=24070240) and [here](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=24078791).

> For instance, a write operation may complete successfully while
>   you are inside a handler but before you have got around to calling
>   socket cancel, causing its completion handler to be posted to the queue.
>   As I understand it, the error code is determined by the status of the
>   operation that completed, not the state of the socket at the time the
>   handler is picked off the queue and executed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider two connections establishing at the same time. Both handlers will fire, one will be handled first, second is in the queue (or being handled on a different thread). One can think of more examples like that.

So in order to implement your requirement you need a bit more logic.