# What if a basic_waitable_timer is destructed when there are still async operations waiting on it?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

What if a basic_waitable_timer is destructed when there are still async operations waiting on it? Is the behavior documented anywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an IO object, such as [`basic_waitable_timer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer.html), is destroyed, its [destructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_io_object/_basic_io_object.html) will invoke `destroy()` on the IO object's service (not to be confused with the `io_service`), passing the IO object's implementation.  A `basic_waitable_timer`'s service is [`waitable_timer_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/waitable_timer_service.html) and fulfills the [WaitableTimerService](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/WaitableTimerService.html) type requirement.  The WaitableTimerService's requirement defines the post-condition for `destroy()` to cancel asynchronous wait operations, causing them to complete as soon as possible, and handler's for cancelled operations will be passed the error code `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.

> `service.destroy(impl);` → Implicitly cancels asynchronous wait operations, as if by calling `service.cancel(impl, e)`.
>
> `service.cancel(impl, e);` → Causes any outstanding asynchronous wait operations to complete as soon as possible. Handlers for cancelled operations shall be passed the error code `error::operation_aborted`. Sets `e` to indicate success or failure.

Note that handlers for operations that have already been queued for invocation will not be cancelled and will have an `error_code` that reflects the success of the operation.

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e4b5cf9273ab206) this behavior:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>

void demo_deferred_completion()
{
  std::cout << "[demo deferred completion]" << std::endl;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  auto wait_completed = false;

  // Use scope to force lifetime.  
  {
    // Create the timer and initiate an async_wait operation that
    // is guaranteed to have expired.
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer(io_service);

    // Post a ready-to-run no-op completion handler into the io_service.
    // Although the order is unspecified, the current implementation
    // will use a predictable order.
    io_service.post([]{});

    // Initiate an async_wait operation that will immediately expire.
    timer.expires_at(boost::asio::steady_timer::clock_type::now());
    timer.async_wait(
        [&](const boost::system::error_code& error)
        {
          std::cout << "error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
          assert(error == boost::system::error_code()); // Success.
          wait_completed = true;          
        });

    // While this will only run one handler (the noop), it will
    // execute operations (async_wait), and if they are succesful
    // (time expired), the completion handler will be posted for
    // deferred completion.
    io_service.run_one();
    assert(!wait_completed); // Verify the wait handler was not invoked.
  } // Destroy the timer.

  // Run the handle_wait completion handler.
  io_service.run();
  assert(wait_completed);
}

void demo_cancelled()
{
  std::cout << "[demo cancelled]" << std::endl;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Use scope to force lifetime.
  {
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer(io_service);

    // Initiate an async_wait operation that will immediately expire.
    timer.expires_at(boost::asio::steady_timer::clock_type::now());
    timer.async_wait(
        [](const boost::system::error_code& error)
        {
          std::cout << "error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
          assert(error ==
                 make_error_code(boost::asio::error::operation_aborted));
        });
  } // Destroy the timer.

  // Run the handle_wait completion handler.
  io_service.run();
}

int main()
{
  demo_deferred_completion();
  demo_cancelled();
}
```

Output:

```
[demo deferred completion]
error: Success
[demo cancelled]
error: Operation canceled
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be canceled: the completion handler is called with an error_code of `operation_aborted`

Relevant background information: [boost::asio async handlers invoked without error after cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718593/boostasio-async-handlers-invoked-without-error-after-cancellation/10822861#10822861)